# remove array php wild

Tags: php, arrays

I apologize for this newbie question. I am trying to remove this

```html
[embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOME_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_UNIQUE_ID[/embed]
```

I managed to use the below.... and it works in my environment, except that I am not sure how to replace SOME_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_UNIQUE_ID with wildcards.

```html
$remove = array('     [embed]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SOME_YOUTUBE_VIDEO_UNIQUE_ID[/embed]');
```

Comment: Remove it from what?

Comment: Zdravo, I understand you want to remove what is after `?v=` but that is all we understand from what you are asking. Where is the code that contains it? why cant you just use the backspace bar. You are missing information in your question in order for us to help you.

Comment: HI all. I am trying to remove everything between the two tags [embed] and [/embed], including the tags themselves. Anyone ? thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have an array of strings which may contain an [embed] ... [/embed] segment which you want to have removed from them. One compact way I can think of is this: ($yourArray is the array of strings containing the embed segment.)

```
preg_replace('#\[embed\].*?\[/embed\]#i', '', $yourArray);
```

Comment: Thank you mwerner, but...

Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g'

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry. This gets me every time: In PHP, there is no global modifier. I have edited my answer. Please give it a try.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I regret my upping does not appear in public yet.